# Problem with generating Querydsl classes with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, querydsl

I want to generate 'Q' classes using querydsl. The problem that I'm facing is described by errors:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED 
Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QIngredientAmount
Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QUser
Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QRating
Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QIngredient
Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QRecipe
error: Attempt to recreate a file for type
com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QIngredientAmount
error: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QUser
error: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QRating
error: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QIngredient
error: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.my.dinner.rest.database.entity.QRecipe
5 errors
```

Files are generated but build is failing, I suppose that classes are generated multiple times but I don't know how to fix it.
I was using tips described here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212487?_ga=2.72682843.91471992.1592753352-1655482529.1589711163#focus=streamItem-27-3491579.0-0

but it does not work in my case.

I've tried every build.gradle configuration that I have found in Google, Github but nothing helped.

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.8'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
group 'com.my.dinner.rest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

def springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
def springFrameworkVersion = '5.2.7.RELEASE'
def lombokVersion = '1.18.12'
def querydslVersion = '4.3.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.4', ext: 'pom'

    // Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: springFrameworkVersion, ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springFrameworkVersion

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion

    // Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.17.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.5.Final'

    // Querydsl
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: querydslVersion
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: querydslVersion
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-core', version: querydslVersion

    // Others
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.8'

    annotationProcessor group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: querydslVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', 'name': 'querydsl-apt', version: querydslVersion, classifier: 'jpa'

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: springBootVersion
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
}

def querydslSrcDir = "$buildDir/generated"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/main/java", querydslSrcDir]
        }
    }
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}

querydsl {
    library = "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt"
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = querydslSrcDir
}

configurations {
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath

    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

clean.doLast {
    file(querydslSrcDir).deleteDir()
}
```

Gradle version: 6.5

Intellij version: 2020.1

Comment: compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    } why?

Comment: Maybe the querydsl plugin is not compatible with the way newer versions of Gradle runs the processor itself when you have the libraries in the annotationProcessor configuration?

Comment: Check the location to where your generated classes are generated. I suspect the error may happen when there is a mess with output paths for generated and normal classes compilation. E.g. `querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath` - not sure but it may change the output paths. Gradle uses [separate output directory](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/release-notes.html#annotation-processor-improvements) for generated classes and you may change it with your configuration.

Answer (score 4):

So i solved it randomly changing build.gradle file.

I deleted unnecessary plugins and a whole section below dependecies and it generated all classes in:

`build/generated/annotationProcessor/java/main`

My updated build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
group 'com.my.dinner.rest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

def springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
def springFrameworkVersion = '5.2.7.RELEASE'
def lombokVersion = '1.18.12'
def querydslVersion = '4.3.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.4', ext: 'pom'

    // Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: springFrameworkVersion, ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springFrameworkVersion

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion

    // Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.17.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.5.Final'

    // Querydsl
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: querydslVersion
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: querydslVersion
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-core', version: querydslVersion

    // Others
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.8'

    annotationProcessor group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: querydslVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', 'name': 'querydsl-apt', version: querydslVersion, classifier: 'jpa'

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: springBootVersion
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
}
```

Versions:

- Java: `11.0.7`
- Gradle: `6.5`
- Intellij: `2020.1.1`
- Ubuntu: `20.04 LTS`

So I think that all questions about this problem that I have looked before were bound with older gradle versions, and there were many workarounds that don't need to be applied in my version of gradle.